# Is there any way to compare array list using contains with multiple condition, code looks like this

Tags: grails, groovy

```
ense.findAll { obj ->
    obj.otherDetails.findAll { od ->
        od.activityType.name.contains('Exporter') && od.activityType.name.contains('Distribution')
    }
}
```

The expected output of this code must retrieve all of the ense's with activity types of Exporter && Distribution

For Example

```
ense 1 has [Exporter, Distribution]
ense 2 has [Hauler]
ense 3 has [Distribution, Exporter]
ense 4 has [Exporter, Refiller]
```

Then the code above must retrieve the ense 1 and ense 3 only

Comment: Please provide a full example of your problem or at the very least, what output you get instead of the expected.

Comment: Already updated, thanks

Comment: I think it's clear, what you want and your code does not look that off.  So what is the result you get for what input? Please add your actual input or some reduced subset to the question, that shows the actual problem.

Comment: what is a "sense"? why is there unnecessary code to your question? simplify the code and the case so the question will be shorter and self explanatory. For what I understand the two findAlls just moving inside your complex object are useless to your question but you just copied some code you had before...

Comment: ` ense 4 has [Exporter, Refiller]` sound like the current contains is returning true/false but you actually want a list containing a map of ense object and then any activityType which it may have , try `def myResults=ense.collect{[it:it.otherDetails.activityType]}?.flatten() `  then `myResults?.each { k,v -> println "${k} = ense object in its whole and value ${v} is a collection or a list of all of its activity types" } `

Answer (score 1):

Just use a regular expression if you want to have only one sentence. In groovy you can check regular expressions like this:

```
def list = ['a','b','c','d']

list.each{
    println it ==~ /a|b/ 
}
```

so ==~ will check the regular expression and returns a boolean, the output will be:

```
true
true
false
false
```

the or is inside the regex as |, you can just replace the regex with the logic that you want (which is really unclear in the question).